# Style does not get added after Importing css into React component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have this class in a CSS file (TextBoxStyle.css) -

```
.CustomTextBox{
width: 100%;
border-radius: 4px;
height: 30px;
}
```

Then I am trying to use this in a React component -

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import styleClass from  './TextBoxStyle.css';

export class TextBox extends React.Component{

render(){      
                return  (
                <input className={styleClass.CustomTextBox}>
                </input>
                );
}
}
```

My project gets build successfully as I have installed all necessary loaders through webpack.

However, the class 'CustomTextBox' does not show up in my final html page.

Please let me know if I need to elaborate on any point.
Highly appreciate any help.

Comment: can you include your `webpack.config.js` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't absolutely need to reference `CustomTextBox`, you could try importing the CSS directly like so:

```
import './TextBoxStyle.css';
```

Then change the className on the input like so:

```
<input className="CustomTextBox">
```